# GCM and App engine for push notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I was wondering if using GCM and app engine would be the best option for my problem. It definitely doesn't seem trivial.

I have a list of shows and users on the android app can subscribe to multiple shows. each show can have multiple times. I would like to send a notification to the user for the shows he/she is subscribed to.

now i can use gcm and register every instance of the app. and then use appengine somehow to constantly run a background service that looks for who it should notify and then push a notification ? Is this the only option or is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better option too, you may use [Google topic messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

You have to subscribe your users to your desired topic, e.g. `show-1` on the android app, then send a push notification to that topic `to: \topics\show-1`(instead of a list of reg-ids).

Then all of the users which had been subscribed to that topic will get the notification.

Comment: also is there is a way where i can schedule time based automatic push messages ?

Comment: You can use GCM [networkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) to scheduled any tasks on your android device.

Comment: Currently you have to manage the scheduling push messages yourself.